# Вывод блока в зависимости от существования файла на vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    data: {
        show: true, 
    },
}

items = [
  {ava: 'use1'},
  {ava: 'use2'},
  {ava: 'use3'},
];
```

```html
<div id="root">
    <div class="item"  v-for="(item, index) in items">
       <div class="img" style="display:none" v-if="show">
          <img  onload="this.parentElement.style.display='block'" 
                v-bind:src="'selfy/'+index+'.jpg'">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

есть такой скрипт который выводит  родительский блок  если фото подгрузилось удачно,

как это реализовать по средствам **vue**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используй функцию `data () { }`
В ней по массиву своему пройдись `axios.head('selfy/'+index+'.jpg')`

Там где ответы успешны запиши их в массив, например images[id]=url.

В шаблоне src доставай из массива.

```
data () { 
 let items = [
  {ava: 'use1'},
  {ava: 'use2'},
  {ava: 'use3'},
];
  items.forEach( function(val,index) {
    axios.head('selfy/'+index+'.jpg').then(
      function(data) {
          val['src'] = 'selfy/'+index+'.jpg'
      }
    )

} )
 return items
}
```

И рисуем блоки только там где есть файлы

```
<div class="item"  v-for="(item, index) in items">
   <div class="img" style="display:none" v-if="item.src" >
      <img v-bind:src="item.src">
  </div>
</div>
```

Элементы появятся не сразу поэтому html будет прыгать.